# Rails 3: How to insert non English text in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to insert non English (e.g. Russian or Hebrew) text in my view.

Is that a good idea to do:

```
<div>что нибудь по русски</div>
```

or

```
<div><%= "משהו בעברית" %></div>
```

or there are better methods ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Rails i18n API. you basically create YAML files for translations of specific pieces of code; it works amazingly well. Here's the guide:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

If you need something more complicated, it's doable, but the Rails i18n API is one of the best.

Comment: In my case I don't really want to translate. It is a very tiny piece of code what should be in that specific language. Would you still use YAML files for that?

Comment: If it only needs to be in one language, and you're using Ruby 1.9.2, it can handle foreign Unicode characters within Strings. Just don't use them outside of those Strings, you should be okay. This post by Yehuda Katz should answer your questions: http://yehudakatz.com/2010/05/17/encodings-unabridged/ . But even if not, the road to forward-compatibility is paved by i18n. Implementing it in Rails 3 is EASY, you could just do it for the target language now and not incur technical debt if you need to internationalize in future.